# you need to specify name or key when calling navigate with an object as the argument

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

i'm having an messages screen and i need to navigate to a "single message" when tapping to the List item of messages but i get this error `"you need to specify name or key when calling navigate with an object as the argument"`

i have created the "single message" screen and added it as a <Stack.Screen/> also but i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

below is my code:

```
function MessagesScreen({navigation}) {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);
    
    const loadMessages = async () => {
        const response = await messagesApi.getMessages();
        setMessages(response.data);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
            loadMessages();
        }, []);

    const handleDelete = message => {

        setMessages(messages.filter((m) => m.id !== message.id));
    }
    
    return (
        <Screen>
            <FlatList
                data={messages}
                keyExtractor={message => message.id.toString()}
                renderItem={({ item }) => 
                    <ListItem 
                    title={item.fromUserId}
                    subTitle={item.content}
                    image={item.image}
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.MESSAGE_SINGLE, item)}
                    renderRightActions={() => 
                        <ListItemDeleteAction onPress={() => handleDelete(item)} />}
                    /> 
                    }
                ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeparator}
                refreshing={refreshing}
                onRefresh={() => {
                    setMessages([
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            title: 'T1',
                            description: 'D1',
                            image: require('../assets/mosh.jpg')
                        },
                    ])
                    //setMessages(loadMessages());
                }}
                />
        </Screen>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    
})

export default MessagesScreen;
```

when i'm logging the "onPress" event on the console like this:

```
onPress={() => console.log('message selected', item)}
```

heres what i get:

[image]

and below is the MessageSingle screen i created to render the message but i dont know how to do it.

```
function MessageSingle() {


  return (
    
    <Screen>
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <AppText>{"kjhkjhjk"}</AppText>
          {/* <AppText>{getMessagesApi}</AppText> */}
      </View>
    </Screen>
        
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {}
});

export default MessageSingle;
```

so i want to get the message from the list of the messages. maybe i dont have to create e separate screen? i'm a beginner on this

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try this: navigation.navigate(routes.MESSAGE_SINGLE, {message: item}) or navigation.navigate(routes.MESSAGE_SINGLE, {params: {message: item}})

Comment: what is `routes.MESSAGE_SINGLE`? the first argument in navigation.navigate() has to be a name of the screen.

Comment: @DánielBoros i get the same error. i updated the question. please check it again.

Comment: @WenW its the screen where i want to navigate after clicking on the message and the message to be rendered there. i updated the question. please check

Comment: @DánielBoros hey guys. i had a terrible typo in the "routes.js" component where i declared the screens. i missed an "S" for the MESSAGE_SINGLE screen. thanks for your effort! i appreciate it

Comment: Sorry for late response. Could you solve the issue?

Comment: @DánielBoros yes it works fine now. i just need to render the message in the `MessageSingle` component. you can contribute on the answer below. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to first add your `MessageSingle` component to the navigation container. Just put it as one of the screens along your `MessagesScreen`component. Then you need to navigate to it using that name:

```
onPress={() => navigation.navigate('MessageSingle', {item})}
```

the above will navigate to the screen with name `MessageSingle`, and passing the object `item` as a param.

in order to access this in your `MessageSingle` component, you need to use the `route` props.

```
function MessageSingle({route}) {

console.log('item = ', route.params?.item); // this would be your item. 

  return (
    
    <Screen>
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <AppText>{"kjhkjhjk"}</AppText>
          {/* <AppText>{getMessagesApi}</AppText> */}
      </View>
    </Screen>
        
  );
}
```

Comment: i had a terrible typo in the "routes.js" component where i declared the screens. i missed an "S" for the MESSAGE_SINGLE screen. thanks for your effort! i appreciate it. now in my MessageSingle component i have `const message = route.params;` and trying to render it like this `<AppText>{message.content}</AppText>` but nothing is rendered. just a blank screen. [link] https://prnt.sc/10rsj9n and my MessagesScreen: [link] https://prnt.sc/10rsldu

Comment: ok it works now. this is what i did: [link]https://prnt.sc/10rv5at
im gonna Accept your answer because it sent me to the right direction. is my code right in terms of using as it should and not violating any security rule? (beginner question)